# Problem with reading from csv file after writing to it in C++

Tags: c++, csv

I'm quite new to C++, I'm trying to achieve a task whereby i could read from a csv file and write to that same file and vice versa depending on the user's selection. This is what i did:

**Here's the data already on file**

1,Mickey,23,090,Girne,TRNC,465

2,Charles,23,090,Girne,TRNC,465

3,Species,23,090,Girne,TRNC,465

4,Moody,23,090,Girne,TRNC,465

5,Kpokiyo,23,090,Girne,TRNC,465

6,Sualp,23,090,Girne,TRNC,465

**Here's the code i wrote so far**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

    using namespace std; 

    bool checkIsFile();
    void addUser(string e[][7], int num);
    void readAllUsers(string x[][7]);
    void breakArray(string x[], string y[][7], int num);
    bool checkAccout(string x[], int y, string search);
    void findUser(string x[], string y[],string z[], string a[],string t[], 
    string c[], string d[]);
    int findRowNumber();

    int main()
    {
        int option;
        int acc;
        string emp[findRowNumber()][7];
        string account[findRowNumber()], age[findRowNumber()],name[findRowNumber()], 
        state[findRowNumber()], city[findRowNumber()], phone[findRowNumber()],
        zip[findRowNumber()];

      //infinite loop
          while(true){
          cout<<"-------------------------\n";
          cout<<"Menu Options\n";
          cout<<"1 Add account\n";
          cout<<"2 List Accounts\n";
          cout<<"3 Delete account\n";
          cout<<"4 Find user\n";
          cout<<"5 Exit program\n";
          cout<<"-------------------------\n";
          cin>>option;

              if(option==1)
              {
                 readAllUsers(emp);
                 addUser(emp, findRowNumber());
              }
              else if(option==2)
              {
                  readAllUsers(emp);
              }
              else if(option==3)
              {
                   //delete a user;
              }
              else if(option==4)
              {
                    //find user
                    readAllUsers(emp);
                    breakArray(account,emp,0);
                    breakArray(name,emp,1);
                    breakArray(age,emp,2);
                    breakArray(phone,emp,3);
                    breakArray(city,emp,4);
                    breakArray(state,emp,5);
                    breakArray(zip,emp,6);

                    findUser(account,name,age,phone,city,state,zip);
              }
              else if(option==5)
              {
                    return 0;
              }
              else
              {
                    cout<<"Invalid option\n";
              }
          }
        }

    void addUser(string e[][7], int num)
    {
         string emp[num + 1][7];

         for(int a=0;a<num;a++)
         {
            for(int b=0;b<7;b++)
            {
                 emp[a][b] = e[a][b];
                 }
                 }
        //just to test if it works 
         emp[num][0] = "10";
         emp[num][1] = "10";
         emp[num][2] = "10";
         emp[num][3] = "10";
         emp[num][4] = "10";
         emp[num][5] = "10";
         emp[num][6] = "10";

         ofstream inFile;
         inFile.open("info.csv");

         for(int a=0;a<num + 1;a++)
         {
            for(int b=0;b<7;b++)
            {
                 cout<<emp[a][b];               
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<num +1; i++)
        {
             inFile << emp[i][0] + "," + emp[i][1] + "," + emp[i][2] + "," + emp[i][3] + "," + emp[i][4] + "," + emp[i][5] + "," + emp[i][6]<<endl;                 
        }

        inFile.close();
    }

    void readAllUsers(string x[][7])
    {
        ifstream inFile("info.csv");
        string line;
        int linenum = 0;
        while (getline (inFile, line))
        {
            istringstream linestream(line);
            string item;
            int itemnum = 0;
            while (getline (linestream, item, ','))
            {
                x[linenum][itemnum] = item;
                itemnum++;
            }
        linenum++;
        }
        inFile.close();
   }

   void breakArray(string x[], string y[][7], int num)
   {       
        for(int i=0;i<findRowNumber();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
            {
                 x[i] = y[i][num];
            }
        }
   }

   bool checkAccout(string x[], int y, string search)
   {
        bool check = false;
        for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
        {
            if(x[i]==search)
            {
                check = true;
            }
        }
       return check;  
   }

   void findUser(string x[], string y[],string z[], string a[], 
    string t[], string c[], string d[])
    {
       string search;
       bool check = false;
       cout<<"Enter Account Number to Search: ";
       cin>>search;

       for(int i=0;i<findRowNumber();i++)
        {
            if(x[i]==search)
            {
                cout<<"Account Number: " + x[i]<<endl<<
                "Name:\t\t" + y[i]<<endl<<
                "Age:\t\t" + z[i]<<endl<<
                "Phone:\t\t" + a[i]<<endl<<
                "City:\t\t" + t[i]<<endl<<
                "State:\t\t" + c[i]<<endl<<
                "Zip:\t\t" + d[i]<<endl;
                check = true;
            }
        }

        if(!check)
            cout<<"User does not exist"<<endl;
    }

    int findRowNumber()
    {
        ifstream inFile("info.csv");
        string line;
        int linenum = 0;
        while (getline (inFile, line))
        {
            linenum++;
        }
        inFile.close();
        return linenum;
    }
```

It seems to work great when i choose to search for a user(selecting 4). However, the problem is when i try to write to file, it's works but when i try to do any other task like searching the user again or re-writing to file, the program crashes. 
Please what i'm i doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `emp` string array in the main function is declared with the initial size of the file and never resized when you add more entries, hence the crash when it tries to read a bigger file into the old size of array.

Comment: Nailed it. You should add an edit and let the OP know that if he uses a vector he doesn't need to count the lines in the file ahead of time!